# How to use function D3DXSaveSurfaceToFile() in C#

Tags: c#, directx, directx-9

I use directx 9 to build model.

I want to save it to bmp file. I found the function D3DXSaveSurfaceToFile()

But I do not know how to use it in C#.

How can I use it?

Comment: AT the very least please post the function.  We can't help you if we can't see the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no such function in c#.
Try the following code instead:

```
try
{

// initialize D3D device 
PresentParameters presentParams = new PresentParameters();
presentParams.Windowed = true;
presentParams.SwapEffect = SwapEffect.Discard;
Device myDevice = new
Device(0,DeviceType.Hardware,this,CreateFlags.SoftwareVertexProcessing,presentParams);

// create a surface the size of screen, 
// format had to be A8R8G8B8, as the GetFrontBufferData returns
// only memory pool types allowed are Pool.Scratch or Pool.System memory
Surface mySurface =
myDevice.CreateOffscreenPlainSurface(SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize.Width,SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize.Height,Format.A8R8G8B8,Pool.SystemMemory);

//Get the front buffer.
myDevice.GetFrontBufferData(0,mySurface);

//saves surface to file
SurfaceLoader.Save("surface.bmp",ImageFileFormat.Bmp,mySurface);

}
catch
{
   //whatever
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But how can I just get the surface not entire screen like that

Comment: You couldn't. Your only option is to cut the needed piece out of the full screenshot.

Comment: Can I rotate the model and create it to avi file?

Comment: Set timer. Rotate the model. Get screenshots. Convert BMP sequence to AVI. Open another question if you want more info.